# php api metacritic

Tags: php, html, curl

Is there any php code/api to metacritic.com to get Release Date, Publisher, Developer, genre and meta score in a certain game?

i know that i can use curl but when i just try to get just the publisher it wont work..

this work

```
$metac['publisher'] = @get_match('/<li class="summary_detail publisher">(.*)<\/li>/isU',$metac_content);
```

this would write out: Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment with link: http://www.metacritic.com/company/warner-bros-interactive-entertainment
but i just want it to write out Publisher: Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment

but this wont work

```
$metac['publisher'] = @get_match('/ <li class="summary_detail publisher"><span class="label">Publisher:</span><span class="data"><a [^>]*>(.*)<\/a><\/span><\/li>/isU',$metac_content);
```

or am i totally lost?

for the record i'm very new to curl.

Comment: I can't find documentation for `get_match`; is it something you wrote?

Comment: no, shad, i used it cause i saw many imdb script used it. and it works smiliar to preg_match http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2):

I checked their site out and they don't have a public api that I can see. Your best bet is to go through some screen scraping tutorials or you could try out yahoo pipes (http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes).